# Calculate total profit/loss

Tags: python, finance

This program starts with initial balance and the individual book balances which must match the initial balance to proceed. The user then enters the selections for the day along with stake, odds etc., then the program calculates the new balance with the new book balances.

```
def main():
    def balances(msg):
        while True:
                    try:
                        x = float(raw_input(msg))
                        return x
                    except ValueError:
                        print"That's not a number"
                        continue

    while True:
        balance = balances('Balance:')
        print
        bfair_balance = balances('bfair:')
        wh_balance = balances('wh:')
        freds_balance = balances('freds:')
        sky_balance = balances('sky:')
        pp_balance = balances('pp:')
        balance_sum = pp_balance + bfair_balance + sky_balance + freds_balance + wh_balance
        if balance == balance_sum:
        # balance is correct -> stop the loop
            break
        else:
            print "Balances do not match"
    print

    print "Balance: %s" %balance
    print "Bfair: %d, Sky: %d, pp: %d, freds: %d, wh: %d" %(bfair_balance, sky_balance, pp_balance, freds_balance, wh_balance)

    books = [bfair_balance, wh_balance, sky_balance,freds_balance,pp_balance]
    #print books




    print


    inputs = []
    new_books = []


    def looks_good(inputs):
                for i in inputs:
                    print i

    while True:

        add_selection =raw_input("Would you like to add a selection? ")
        if add_selection == "Yes":
            print
            selection = raw_input('Horse: ')

            stake = float(raw_input('Stake: '))
            while stake <=0:
                print "Please enter a stake greater than 0"
                stake = float(raw_input('Stake: '))
            while stake > bfair_balance:
                print "You do not have sufficient funds"
                stake = float(raw_input('Stake: '))
            while stake > pp_balance:
                 print "You do not have sufficient funds"
                 stake = float(raw_input('Stake: '))
            while stake > freds_balance:
                 print "You do not have sufficient funds"
                 stake = float(raw_input('Stake: '))
            while stake > sky_balance:
                 print "You do not have sufficient funds"
                 stake = float(raw_input('Stake: '))
            while stake > wh_balance:
                 print "You do not have sufficient funds"
                 stake = float(raw_input('Stake: '))


            odds = float(raw_input('Odds: '))
            while odds <=0:
                print "Please enter odds greater than 0"
                odds = float(raw_input('Odds: '))

            result = (raw_input('Result: '))
            if result == "Win":
                result = stake * odds
                print "Returns:%d"%result
            elif result == "Lose":
                result = 0 * odds
                print "Returns:%d"%result

            book = raw_input('Book: ')

            while book not in['bfair','sky','wh','freds','pp']:
                print "That's not valid"
                book = raw_input('Book: ')

            if result == 0 and book == "bfair":
                bfair_balance = bfair_balance - stake
                new_books.append(bfair_balance)
            elif result == (stake * odds) and  book == "bfair":
                bfair_balance = bfair_balance - stake + (stake * odds)
                new_books.append(bfair_balance)

            if result == 0 and book == "freds":
                freds_balance = freds_balance - stake
                new_books.append(freds_balance)
            elif result == (stake * odds) and  book == "freds":
                freds_balance = freds_balance - stake + (stake * odds)
                new_books.append(freds_balance)

            if result == 0 and book == "pp":
                pp_balance = pp_balance - stake
                new_books.append(pp_balance)
            elif result == (stake * odds) and  book == "pp":
                pp_balance = pp_balance - stake + (stake * odds)
                new_books.append(pp_balance)

            if result == 0 and book == "wh":
                wh_balance = wh_balance - stake
                print wh_balance - stake
                new_books.append(wh_balance)
            elif result == (stake * odds) and  book == "wh":
                wh_balance = wh_balance - stake + (stake * odds)
                new_books.append(wh_balance)

            if result == 0 and book == "sky":
                sky_balance = sky_balance - stake
                new_books.append(sky_balance)
            elif result == (stake * odds) and  book == "sky":
                sky_balance = sky_balance - stake + (stake * odds)
                new_books.append(sky_balance)


            my_list=[selection,stake,odds,result,book]

            inputs.append(my_list)
            print
            total_stake=[]
            for my_list in inputs:
                total_stake.append(my_list[1])
            print "Total Stake: %d" %sum(total_stake)

            total_winnings = []
            for my_list in inputs:
                total_winnings.append(my_list[3])
            print "Total Winnings: %d" %sum(total_winnings)
            print
            new_balance = balance - sum(total_stake) + sum(total_winnings)
            print "New Balance:%d" %new_balance

            print "Bfair: %d, Sky: %d, pp: %d, freds: %d, wh: %d" %(bfair_balance, sky_balance, pp_balance, freds_balance, wh_balance)
            print

        elif add_selection == "No":
             break



        looks_good(inputs)



    import os
    os.system("pause")

if __name__ == '__main__':
            main()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use loops to avoid repetition

For example you have:

```
while stake > bfair_balance: 
    print "You do not have sufficient funds"
    stake = float(raw_input('Stake: '))
# many very similar blocks
```

You should use a loop to avoid repetition:

```
for balance in [bfair_balance, ...]:
    while stake > balance: 
        print "You do not have sufficient funds"
        stake = float(raw_input('Stake: '))
```

Comment: Well thank you. It looks like I need to try harder and perfect the code before asking on here. It turns out I need to use a dictionary rather than a list. I want to see how far I can get wihtout posting on here, thanks for the help mate.